# Variable scope access on a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I come from an ExtJS background and am slowly learning jQuery. I am trying to access the value of an option/property I added `myVar` to a Dialog from the `open` event of the dialog.

```
$("#add-family-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 450,
    width: 600,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    myVar: "hello world!",
    open: function(event, ui) { 
        // TODO: get the myVar value
        // this
        alert($(this).myVar);
        // or this
        alert($(this).attr("myVar"));
        // or this
        alert(this.myVar);
    }
});
```

How can I access `myVar`'s value? Is this the correct way to do this or is there a better method of holding variables on an object?

Comment: If you want to store values against DOM elements have a look at jQuery's [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it through the `'option'` method:

```
var myVar = $(this).dialog('option', 'myVar');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ww5Gm/

I don't know if this is specified or accidental behavior though so I wouldn't depend on it. A more natural approach (IMO) would be to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach your extra data:

```
$('.dialog').data('myVar', 'hello world!').dialog({
    // ...
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var myVar = $(this).data('myVar');
        // ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/R9z8D/

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "myVar" is not part of the options of the plugin dialog (jquery ui), you can't add additional arbitrary variables to the constructor of dialog.

In my opinion a better approach is to have your variable outside the dialog:

```
var myVar='hello world';
$( "#add-family-dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 450,
    width: 600,
    resizable : false,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) { 
        alert(myVar);
    }
});
```

...or get the value of a hidden html element in your page

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVar" value="hello world" />
```

...in javascript

```
alert($('#myVar').val());
```

I hope this helps.